# When overriding keys, what is the Open Parenthesis key called (PyQt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, keyboard, pyqt5

I'm trying to override keys in PyQt5 using keyPressOverride and have been having trouble figuring out what the Open Parenthesis Key is called.

For other keys I've accessed them in the following way:

`Qt.Key_0` for the '0' key

`Qt.Key_Plus` for the '+' key

but I can't figure out what the Open Parennthesis key is called.

(`Qt.Key_OpenParenthesis` did not work)

Comment: I tried looking up some sort of documentary that has a list of the names but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: `Qt.Key_ParenLeft`